# How to resize equations

Tags: equations

I am writing an article, and I am having some trouble making my equations large enough to stand out on the page.  Does anyone have a suggestion on how to best resize this?

Thanks

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb,}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlot, notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{bm,nicefrac}

\begin{document}

\subsection{My Text Begins Below}
Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here.
    \begin{center}

    \boldmath

        \[
    \underbrace{
\mathit{}  
\frac{x_n({A^{x+y}})}{b}
}\unboldmath_{\text{{\begin{huge}$=c$\end{huge}}}}
\]
    \unboldmath

    \underbrace

    Figure 1: My equation above.

    \unboldmath

    \end{center}

\end {document}
```

Comment: I guess you may not like this suggestion: do not make the equation larger to "stand out". Of course, this is just my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You could have several options; a quick way could be the following:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb,}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\usepackage[nottoc, notlot, notlof]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{bm,nicefrac}

\begin{document}

\subsection{My Text Begins Below}
Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here Text Here.
    \begin{center}\huge

    \boldmath

        \[
    \underbrace{
\mathit{}  
\frac{x_n({A^{x+y}})}{b}
}\unboldmath_{\text{{\begin{huge}$=c$\end{huge}}}}
\]
    \normalsize
    \unboldmath

    \underbrace

    Figure 1: My equation above.

    \unboldmath

    \end{center}

\end {document}
```

You could find the font sizes here: https://it.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Font_sizes,_families,_and_styles.

I personally would prefer to use the `equation` environment.

You can find more ways to change the size at the following link:https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Advanced_Mathematics

Comment: Let me know if that's what you were looking for.

Comment: This provided [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301)  does not compile for me. Fails with "_Paragraph ended before `\underbrace` was complete_".

Comment: It's the given MWE with two additions that could not inhibit the compilation. It works for me.